# PHP and MySQL insert successful but can't see that the row has been inserted in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple registration form that inserts data into MySQL table. I am checking for error as well but it results in SUCCESS echo. 
On Stackoverflow, I looked for the question, but couldn't really find an answer pertaining to my situation. Please forgive me if it has been answered. If it has been answered already, please provide a link and I will apologize for wasting anybody's time. Thank you! Below is my code:

```
<?php
if($_GET["regname"] && $_GET["regpass1"] && $_GET["regpass2"])
{
if($_GET["regpass1"]==$_GET["regpass2"])
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password='';
$conn= mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="INSERT INTO members('id','username','password')VALUES('DEFAULT','$_GET[regname]','$_GET[regpass1]')";

if($sql)
{
echo "Success";

}
else
{
echo "Error";

}

print "<h1>you have registered sucessfully</h1>";

print "<a href='main_login.php'>go to login page</a>";
}
else print "passwords doesnt match";
}
else print"invaild data";
?>
```

Comment: You are checking if $sql exists. $sql is your actual query string. In this case, of course it will show it exists. Secondly, please do not use `mysql_*` for new code as it is deprecated. Instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: You are not running a query. All you have done so far it initialize a string that is a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members('id','username','password')VALUES('DEFAULT','$_GET[regname]','$_GET[regpass1]')";

if($sql)
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

You have created a request in $sql variable but have not executed it. The variable itself is non-empty, non-false so it evaluates to TRUE in the if-condition.

You should do it like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members('id','username','password')VALUES('DEFAULT','$_GET[regname]','$_GET[regpass1]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) 
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Just to be on the safe side I'll note that using variables from $_GET request like this, unfiltered, is an **inapprorpiate** tactic as it will lead to SQL injections, but I suppose you simplified code sample for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Vaviloff, Thank you so much! With the mysql_error, it gives me a syntax error: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username','password') VALUES ('ajaygshah','1234')' at line 1. I am looking at the quotes etc, everything seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @user2840743 NEVER enter user input as it is. Right now you can only sanitize it by using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I CAN HAS CHEEZBURGER I tried doing that as well right now. Still stuck with the same error. I looked all over the web but they talk about auto_increment and i have already taken care of that as well.

Comment: THis has been resolved. I had to remove the quotes for the column names. Easy fix. Geez I am such a noob. Sorry for the trouble. Now onto what on earth is MySQL injection. PDO etc.. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking if $sql exists. $sql is your actual query string. In this case, of course it will show it exists. Secondly, please do not use `mysql_*` for new code as it is deprecated. Instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

You actually haven't executed your query in your code. **(Using deprecated `mysql_*` which is ill advised)** the code as follows should execute the query:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if($result == true)
    echo 'Success';
else
    echo 'Failure';
```

Instead of using the code above, I would strongly recommend updating your current code to use [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) forms. You can read up more on this topic at the manpages linked previously.